# Distinct operator on List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, axapta

I'm trying to get distinct string values out of an Ax repository, but I'm getting a lot of identical strings out (strings only contains numbers)

```
var ret = context.XInventTransBackOrder
    .Where(i => i.BatchRouteId != "")
    .Select(i => i.BatchRouteId)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the type of BatchRouteId ?

Comment: A Sample of the data would be nice.

Comment: Yes BatchRouteId is a string

Comment: Maybe need trim? var ret = context.XInventTransBackOrder.Where(i => i.BatchRouteId != "").Select(i => i.BatchRouteId.Trim()).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: I tried this out and it worked for me so you got something funky going on.  If BatchRouteId is a string and the strings in question are actually identical, then Distinct() would remove them.  So either a) BatchRouteId isn't really a string, or b) these identical strings aren't actually identical.

Comment: It looks like you're using Linq-to-AX, which version are you using? Distinct seems to be supported in the AX 2012 version according to Microsoft's documentation, but your question doesn't specify exactly which LINQ library you're using here... (see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj677293.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried

```
var ret = context.XInventTransBackOrder
    .Where(i => i.BatchRouteId != "")
    .Select(i => i.BatchRouteId)
    .ToList();
ret = ret
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The one hundred dollar question is: Why?

Comment: Be careful with this, this can be very expensive, depending on the number of items returned the original list. This first fetches everything to your system and then creates distinct values in memory. What type is your context? Is it converting to some type of AX query or webservice call? Does that API understand the concept of Distinct?

Comment: My context is a **LinqToDynamicsAx** context. I get 10 distinct strings. Otherwise I get 116 strings. Not sure if API understands distinct. It changes the C# code to X++

Answer (score 4):

If the `BatchRouteId` was a `XElement`, for instance, then probably an object reference comparison would be performed. In that case change the code to

```
var ret = context.XInventTransBackOrder
    .Where(i => i.BatchRouteId != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.BatchRouteId.Value))
    .Select(i => i.BatchRouteId.Value)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

Note that some types implement implicit conversions making you think they were another type. You can pass a `string` to a `XName` parameter without explicit casting, and the `string` will automatically be converted to `XName`.

---

**UPDATE #2**

According to a comment of nk2003dec the context is `LinqToDynamicsAx`. I don't know this interface but probably it does not implement `Distinct`. What you can to in such a case, is to change the context form a XY-LINQ to Object-LINQ by using the `System.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable<TSource>` extension method

```
var ret = context.XInventTransBackOrder
    .Select(i => i.BatchRouteId)
    .Where(id => id != "")
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

I also inverted `Select` and `Where` as this simplifies the access to `BatchRouteId`

Answer (score 2):

X++ does not have a distinct operator. The deferred execution will try to execute on ToList() and will fail because of this.